# SqlBulkCopy from MySQL database to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, database, database-migration

I'm attempting to bulk-copy some data from a MySQL DB to a SQL Server DB, using the C# SqlBulkCopy class. The code runs without any exceptions, but no data appears in the SQL Server DB. What am I doing wrong?

```
// Fetched source data successfully from MySQL DB at this point
MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

using (SqlConnection conn = connectionString)
{
    conn.Open();

    // Copy data to SQL Server DB
    using (SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(conn.ConnectionString))
    {
        sbc.DestinationTableName = "TargetTable";
        sbc.BatchSize = 1000;
        sbc.NotifyAfter = 1000;

        sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("sourceCol1", "targetCol1");
        sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("sourceCol2", "targetCol2");
        sbc.WriteToServer(rdr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved - the column mappings between the source and target tables were not exact. Check your column mappings!

Comment: Delete your question then

Comment: @RemusRusanu It's allowable on StackOverflow to answer your own question, as it can still help others in the future